# Difference between installing an apk with adb and eclipse

Tags: android, installation, apk, adb

I have an app that closes itself after it's finished. If I install it through eclipse, it works normally, but if I install it through `adb -e or -d install c:\....\myApp.apk`, it works but it doesn't close itself after finished.

I need to install it via adb and I need it to close when it's done, like it does when installing from eclipse. Why does it have different behavior for the same apk and how can i fix this?

thanks

Comment: The only difference I can think of off hand is, installing an APK via adb installs the APK with the a different signing key, typically, the one used to release an app on say, Google Play. Installing via Eclipse, always uses the default `debug.keystore` to sign an APK for testing purposes. But I don't see how that will affect the functioning, unless it depends on how it was signed.

Comment: why does your app closes itself ?

Comment: Siddharth Lele, I didn't know that, but I don't think that can cause this, the only thing that changes it that when i execute `myActivity.finish()`, it doesn't finish when installed with adb.
njzk2, the app is called several times in a row, so it does his function, closes itself and then he is ready to be called again. The output that is important is collected via LogCat

Comment: Siddharth Lele, you were right, the signing key was the problem. Now I exported the apk with eclipse's default key and it's working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Siddharth Lele posted, the difference was on the signing key, exporting the apk with eclipse's default key fixed the problem.